# How to find the Fourier series of an output given input and transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, transmission-line, fourier, square

I have an input rectangle pulse, \$f(t) = rect(t/\tau) \$ and a transmission line whose transfer function depends on frequency. The transfer function of the t.l. is the transmitted wave divided by the incoming wave: \$(1+\Gamma)/((e^{j\gamma l}) +  \Gamma e^{-j\gamma l})\$.

\$\Gamma\$ is the reflection coefficient. \$\Gamma = \left(Z_L-Z_0\right)/\left(Z_L+Z_0\right)\$

where \$ Z_0=\sqrt{\left(R^\prime+jwL^\prime\right)/\left(G^\prime+jwC^\prime\right)}\$ is the characteristic impedance of the line, \$Z_L \$ is a constant

\$\gamma\$ is the propagation constant. \$ \gamma=\sqrt{\left(R^\prime\ +\ jwL^\prime\right)\left(G^\prime+jwC^\prime\right)}\$

The transfer function \$H(s)\$  is now a complex function where \$s=j\omega\$. I am looking to plot \$g(t) \$ which would be the inverse fourier transform of \$F(s)H(s) \$. I also know how to obtain the Fourier series coefficients for \$f(t) \$, but I am not sure what to do with these.

How should I proceed to obtain the output function in the time domain?

Comment: Treat the input as a step change and multiply the Laplace T.F. by \$\dfrac{1}{s}\$ then do the reverse Laplace using tables and there you have it.

Comment: Fourier series applies to periodic signals. This is not the case here.

Comment: So what do you suggest @Chu

Comment: @Andyaka I don't think I can simplify this to the point where I can use a table

Comment: How good at partial fractions are you?

Comment: Even once I do partial fractions, I still cannot simplify them enough to a Laplace form @Andyaka

Comment: \$H(\omega)\$ is not a transfer function, it's a Fourier transform. Do you mean \$H(j\omega)\$? Also, the square root looks a bit dodgy for a transfer function. Perhaps if you give the actual wording of the problem things would become clearer. It seems this is an XY problem.

Comment: Alright, I do not think that will help much seeing as I only needed to simplify H(s), but I have done as you asked. The problem remains.